# Vectorize conditional cumsum

Tags: python, pandas

i am working with a pandas df: for each row i want to take the date and the value of column shop of that row, select all rows with the same shop and with date < original_row_date - 15 d and compute the occurrences of a value in a third column.

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

from tqdm import tqdm 

cum_items = []

data.execution_date = pd.to_datetime(data.execution_date, errors="coerce")

subset = data[["shop", "execution_date", "item"]]
for i, row in tqdm(subset.iterrows(), total=len(subset)):
    fdf = (subset
           .loc[(subset.shop == row["shop"])]
           .loc[subset.execution_date < (row["execution_date"] - pd.Timedelta(15, unit='d'))]
          )
    
    if len(fdf) == 0: 
        cum_items.append(np.nan)
    else: 
        cum_items.append(fdf.query("item == 'stuff'").shape[0])

data["cum_items"] = cum_items
```

Is there a way to vectorize this snippet? The code is taking a lot to run. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like you want to do a groupby('shop').rolling('15') sum.

Comment: The @ScottBoston's idea is great. You just have to preserve the original index because `groupby_rolling` override your index.

Comment: Remember to call as `rolling(pd.Timedelta(15, unit='d'))`.

Comment: A small tip: do not append to a list like this. If you know in advance the number of items, preallocate it. Even better if you use `numpy.array` or `pd.Series`, since you will insert it into a DataFrame at the end.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @ScottBoston, you have to use `groupby_rolling`.

```
# Because you lose the order after groupby_rolling, you have to preserve it
subset = data.sort_values(['shop', 'execution_date'])

data['cum_items'] = (subset.groupby('shop')
                           .rolling('15D', on='execution_date')['item']
                           .sum().set_axis(subset.index)
```

Output:

```
>>> data
    shop execution_date  item  cum_items
0      1     2023-11-01     0        0.0
1      2     2023-11-03     1        1.0
2      1     2023-11-05     2        2.0
3      2     2023-11-07     3        4.0
4      1     2023-11-09     4        6.0
5      2     2023-11-11     5        9.0
6      1     2023-11-13     6       12.0
7      2     2023-11-15     7       16.0
8      1     2023-11-17     8       20.0
9      2     2023-11-19     9       24.0
10     1     2023-11-21    10       28.0
11     2     2023-11-23    11       32.0
12     1     2023-11-25    12       36.0
13     2     2023-11-27    13       40.0
14     1     2023-11-29    14       44.0
15     2     2023-12-01    15       48.0
16     1     2023-12-03    16       52.0
17     2     2023-12-05    17       56.0
18     1     2023-12-07    18       60.0
19     2     2023-12-09    19       64.0
20     1     2023-12-11    20       68.0
21     2     2023-12-13    21       72.0
22     1     2023-12-15    22       76.0
23     2     2023-12-17    23       80.0
24     1     2023-12-19    24       84.0
25     2     2023-12-21    25       88.0
26     1     2023-12-23    26       92.0
27     2     2023-12-25    27       96.0
28     1     2023-12-27    28      100.0
29     2     2023-12-29    29      104.0
```